# Next js - Setting DOM element scrollHeight in parent component from child component

Tags: javascript, dom, next.js

I have created an accordion within an accordion
[image]

/pages/profile.js passes all the data the first component /components/loved_one.js which renders the first DOM container. When the container button is clicked, the toggleAccordion function sets the scrollheight of the ref content (the container of the accordion within). Which works great as none of the elements within are expanded, and so the height is calculated.

The accordion within /components/event.js does the same thing. However this now expands and the parent accordion container above is now too small.

[image]

If I collapse and expand the parent accordion, it works, as the inner elements are expanded and so can set the correct height again.

So I'm trying to find a way, when I set the height of the inner accordion container, I also trigger the parent accordion container to re-address it's height.

Anyone know how I could do this? Appreciate any help.

Here's the code: -

/pages/profile.js

```js
  export const Profile = ({ loved_ones, events, messages, mementos }) => {
  const [session, loading] = useSession();
  if (loading) return <div>loading...</div>;
  if (!session) return <div>no session</div>;
  return (
    <Layout>
      {session && (
        <>
          <h1>{session.user.name}</h1>
        </>
      )}
      {loved_ones.map((loved_one, index) => (
        <LovedOne
          key={index}
          id={loved_one.id}
          firstname={loved_one.firstname}
          surname={loved_one.surname}
          email={loved_one.email}
          events={events}
          messages={messages}
          mementos={mementos}
        />
      ))}

      <style jsx>{`
        .avatar {
          width: 220px;
          border-radius: 10px;
        }
      `}</style>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(req, res) {
  const session = await getSession(req);
  const prisma = new PrismaClient({
    log: ["query", "info", "warn"],
  });

  if (!session) {
    return {
      props: {},
      redirect: {
        destination: "/login",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }
  const loved_one = await prisma.loved_one.findMany({
    where: {
      user_id: session.user.user_id,
    },
  });

  const events = await prisma.events.findMany({
    where: {
      user_id: session.user.user_id,
    },
  });

  const messages = await prisma.messages.findMany({
    where: {
      user_id: session.user.user_id,
    },
  });

  const mementos = await prisma.mementos.findMany({
    where: {
      user_id: session.user.user_id,
    },
    include: {
      package_size: true,
    },
  });

  const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(loved_one);
  const loved_ones_data = JSON.parse(stringifiedData);

  const stringifiedDataEvents = safeJsonStringify(events);
  const events_data = JSON.parse(stringifiedDataEvents);

  const stringifiedDataMessages = safeJsonStringify(messages);
  const messages_data = JSON.parse(stringifiedDataMessages);

  const stringifiedDataMementos = safeJsonStringify(mementos);
  const mementos_data = JSON.parse(stringifiedDataMementos);

  return {
    props: {
      loved_ones: loved_ones_data,
      events: events_data,
      messages: messages_data,
      mementos: mementos_data,
    },
  };
}

export default Profile;
```

/components/loved_one.js

```js
  export const LovedOne = (props) => {
  const [setActive, setActiveState] = useState("");
  const [setHeight, setHeightState] = useState("0px");
  const [setIcon, setIconState] = useState("fas fa-plus");
  const content = useRef();
  function toggleAccordion() {
    setActiveState(setActive === "" ? "active" : "");
    setHeightState(
      setActive === "active" ? "0px" : `${content.current.scrollHeight}px`
    );
    setIconState(setActive === "active" ? "fas fa-plus" : "fas fa-minus");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="item-container teal lighten-5">
        <div className="row item teal darken-1">
          <div className="col m1">
            <button className={`expand ${setActive}`} onClick={toggleAccordion}>
              <i className={`${setIcon} white-text small`}></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="col m4 item-title">
            <span className="teal-text text-darken-4">Loved One: </span>
            {props.firstname} {props.surname}
          </div>
          <div className="col m5 item-title">
            <span className="teal-text text-darken-4">Email: </span>
            {props.email}
          </div>
          <div className="col m1 offset-m1">
            <button className="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light">
              <i className="fas fa-trash-alt white-text small"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          className="item-content"
          ref={content}
          style={{ maxHeight: `${setHeight}` }}
        >
          {props.events.map((loved_one_event, index) => {
            if (props.id === loved_one_event.loved_one_id)
              return (
                <Event
                  key={index}
                  id={loved_one_event.id}
                  loved_one_id={loved_one_event.loved_one_id}
                  date={loved_one_event.date}
                  anniversary={loved_one_event.anniversary}
                  messages={[props.messages]}
                  mementos={props.mementos}
                />
              );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default LovedOne;
```

/components/events.js

```js
export const Event = (props) => {
  const [setActive, setActiveState] = useState("");
  const [setHeight, setHeightState] = useState("0px");
  const [setIcon, setIconState] = useState("fas fa-plus");
  const content = useRef();
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

  function toggleAccordion() {
    setActiveState(setActive === "" ? "active" : "");
    setHeightState(
      setActive === "active" ? "0px" : `${content.current.scrollHeight}px`
    );
    setIconState(setActive === "active" ? "fas fa-plus" : "fas fa-minus");
  }

   return (
    <>
      <div className="item-container teal lighten-4">
        <div className="row event teal lighten-1">
          <div className="col m1">
            <button className={`expand ${setActive}`} onClick={toggleAccordion}>
              <i className={`${setIcon} white-text small`}></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="col m4 item-title">
            <span className="teal-text text-darken-4">Event Date: </span>
          </div>
          <div className="col m3 item-title">
            <span className="teal-text text-darken-4">Anniversary: </span>
            {props.anniversary}
          </div>
          <div className="col m1 offset-m2">
            <button className="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light">
              <i className="fas fa-trash-alt white-text small"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          className="event-content"
          ref={content}
          style={{ maxHeight: `${setHeight}` }}
        >
          {props.messages[0].map((message, index) => {
            if (props.id === message.event_id)
              return (
                <Message
                  key={index}
                  id={message.id}
                  event_id={message.event_id}
                  content={message.content}
                />
              );
          })}
        </div>
        <div
          className="event-content"
          ref={content}
          style={{ maxHeight: `${setHeight}` }}
        >
          {props.mementos.map((memento, index) => {
            if (props.id === memento.event_id)
              return (
                <Memento
                  key={index}
                  id={memento.id}
                  event_id={memento.event_id}
                  package_size={memento.package_size}
                />
              );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Event;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found what to do. I needed to set the height to auto, rather than the maxHeight

```css
.item-content {
          overflow: hidden;
          height: 0px;
          transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
        }
```

```js
function toggleAccordion() {
    setActiveState(setActive === "" ? "active" : "");
    setHeightState(setActive === "active" ? "0px" : `auto`);
    setIconState(setActive === "active" ? "fas fa-plus" : "fas fa-minus");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="item-container teal lighten-5">
        <div className="row item teal darken-1">
          <div className="col m1">
            <button className={`expand ${setActive}`} onClick={toggleAccordion}>
              <i className={`${setIcon} white-text small`}></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="col m4 item-title">
            <span className="teal-text text-darken-4">Loved One: </span>
            {props.firstname} {props.surname}
          </div>
          <div className="col m5 item-title">
            <span className="teal-text text-darken-4">Email: </span>
            {props.email}
          </div>
          <div className="col m1 offset-m1">
            <button className="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light">
              <i className="fas fa-trash-alt white-text small"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          className="item-content"
          ref={content}
          style={{ height: `${setHeight}` }}
        >
```